# Python generated file does not execute properly

Tags: python, cmake, sh

I have a problem with files I generated with Python. I have some files (.sh-files) that I want to create dynamically. The files themselves can be executed properly and do what they are supposed to.

The Python generated files however are IDENTICAL, the `diff` command in Linux has an empty result! But when I execute the generated .sh scripts, they give me random errors.

Here is my normal file (for example):

```
OBJDUMP=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump`
OBJCOPY=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy`

COMPILER=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc`
RANLIB=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-ranlib`

VSIM=`which vsim`
echo $VSIM

TARGET_C_FLAGS="-O3 -m32 -g"
#TARGET_C_FLAGS="-O2 -g -falign-functions=16  -funroll-all-loops"

# if you want to have compressed instructions, set this to 1
RVC=0

# if you are using zero-riscy, set this to 1, otherwise it uses RISCY
USE_ZERO_RISCY=0

# set this to 1 if you are using the Floating Point extensions for riscy only
RISCY_RV32F=0

# zeroriscy with the multiplier
ZERO_RV32M=0
# zeroriscy with only 16 registers
ZERO_RV32E=0

# riscy with PULPextensions, it is assumed you use the ETH GCC Compiler
GCC_MARCH="IMXpulpv2"
#compile arduino lib
ARDUINO_LIB=1

PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY=../../
SIM_DIRECTORY="$PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY/vsim"
#insert here your post-layout netlist if you are using IMPERIO
PL_NETLIST=""

cmake "$PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY"/sw/ \
    -DPULP_MODELSIM_DIRECTORY="$SIM_DIRECTORY" \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="$COMPILER" \
    -DVSIM="$VSIM" \
    -DRVC="$RVC" \
    -DRISCY_RV32F="$RISCY_RV32F" \
    -DUSE_ZERO_RISCY="$USE_ZERO_RISCY" \
    -DZERO_RV32M="$ZERO_RV32M" \
    -DZERO_RV32E="$ZERO_RV32E" \
    -DGCC_MARCH="$GCC_MARCH" \
    -DARDUINO_LIB="$ARDUINO_LIB" \
    -DPL_NETLIST="$PL_NETLIST" \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="$TARGET_C_FLAGS" \
    -DCMAKE_OBJCOPY="$OBJCOPY" \
    -DCMAKE_OBJDUMP="$OBJDUMP"
```

And here is the python generated one.

```
OBJDUMP=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump`
OBJCOPY=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy`    

COMPILER=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc`
RANLIB=`which riscv32-unknown-elf-ranlib`    

VSIM=`which vsim`
TARGET_C_FLAGS="-O3 -m32 -g"    

RVC=0   

USE_ZERO_RISCY=0   

RISCY_RV32F=0   

ZERO_RV32M=0    

ZERO_RV32E=0    

GCC_MARCH="IMXpulpv2"   

ARDUINO_LIB=1    

PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY=../../
SIM_DIRECTORY="$PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY/vsim"
PL_NETLIST=""
cmake "$PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY"/sw/ \ 
    -DPULP_MODELSIM_DIRECTORY="$SIM_DIRECTORY" \ 
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="$COMPILER" \ 
    -DVSIM="$VSIM" \ 
    -DRVC="$RVC" \ 
    -DRISCY_RV32F="$RISCY_RV32F" \ 
    -DUSE_ZERO_RISCY="$USE_ZERO_RISCY" \ 
    -DZERO_RV32M="$ZERO_RV32M" \ 
    -DZERO_RV32E="$ZERO_RV32E" \ 
    -DGCC_MARCH="$GCC_MARCH" \ 
    -DARDUINO_LIB="$ARDUINO_LIB" \ 
    -DPL_NETLIST="$PL_NETLIST" \ 
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="$TARGET_C_FLAGS" \ 
    -DCMAKE_OBJCOPY="$OBJCOPY" \ 
    -DCMAKE_OBJDUMP="$OBJDUMP"
```

I dont know how much this will help you. But that's how it is.

Now I execute this scripts with `./script` and the first script executes. The second one gives me the error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "../sw/build/ " does not exist.
```

And the path where the script resides in is exactly `../sw/build/`

What's going on here?

Comment: What arguments do you run your `diff` with?

Comment: no arguments (?)

Comment: Are you executing both scripts from the same working directory? The fact that the error references a relative path raises a red flag. (The error also seems inconsistent with the value of `PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY`.)

Comment: Yes i can literally put both files into 'sw/build/' and the one will execute and the other one wont.

Comment: Your Python-generated script, at least as reproduced here, is *not* identical to the other one. There is whitespace after the line-continuation characters, which means `cmake` is only being run with 2 arguments: `"$PULP_GIT_DIRECTORY"` and a literal space (produce by the backslash).

Comment: can you tell me which exact part i need to correct? That would be really nice :)

Comment: @NumanTakács: The previous commenter means that you have exceeded whitespace character after backslash in the line started with `cmake`. You need delete it. BTW, the first script has several comments, but the last script has no comments. I wonder how do you run `diff` and find no differences between the scripts.

Comment: The script above is the one where i dont delete the comments before i read the file in to copy it. But ty very much :)

Comment: @chepner Your answer is right and it totally works now. I thank you very much.